# Can I mark IBM MQ messages as dirty?

Tags: ibm-mq

I do have the following (multi-threaded) process in place:

1. Browse MQ queue (with lock) and get the next available message
2. Do something with it which might or might not fail
3. a. If successful, remove message from queue and start over or b. if not successful, leave message on queue

My problem arises from the fact that my application could die unexpectedly between step 2 and 3 and the application would then produce a duplicated message upon restart.

Is there a way to mark a message as 'dirty' or 'processing' on the queue (while or after reading it) with the mark persisting even if the application restarts?

I have tried to use the marks provided by MQ, but they do not survive a restart. Another possibility would be to move the message to a 'processing' queue, remove it on success or move it back to the source queue on failure, but this requires a second queue and is not trivial code anymore.

Rough code example:

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); 
gmo.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST | MQConstants.MQGMO_LOCK;
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
message.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
message.messageId     = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
queue.get(message, gmo);

boolean success = processMessage(message);

// Application gets killed here after successful message processing.
// Produces duplicate after restart.

if (success) {
   MQGetMessageOptions gmo2 = new MQGetMessageOptions(); 
   gmo2.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR;
   queue.get(new MQMessage(), gmo2);
}
```

Basically, I'd like to achieve this:

- get message non-destructively from queue (only if not marked as "processing")
- mark message as "processing" on queue
- process message (including sending to some destination)
- if successful delete from queue, or remove "processing" state on queue otherwise

If the application dies right after a successful third step 'process message', the message would be marked as "processing" and would not be processed again (as it might have been already).

**Note:** I do not want this process to have any knowledge about the message processing (other than success).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SYNCPOINT?Commit or Backout kind of operation might help in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I have. The problem remains: what if the application dies just before `qmgr.commit()`? The message is then made available again on the queue.

Comment: But it wont be a duplicate message.It is the same message that rollsback.I had tried your application as well and it is working as expected.When you say duplicate message you mean the message rolling back?

Comment: If you use SYNCPOINT,if a message is rolled back,the "backout count" property of the message tells you how many times the message was accessed.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: I need to avoid that `processMessage(message)` gets executed more than once. If I rollback after this statement I'll get a duplicate next time I start the application. Regarding the second: that I did not know. This could indeed help. Is there a way do differentiate between the application calling `backout()` and the message being backed out automatically (because of an application crash)?

Comment: Please go through the link.It is about Avoiding repeated delivery of browsed messages.It might help you 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg20560_.htm

Comment: I've read that, but the marks have the problem that they do not persist. In my understanding all marks are lost as soon as the application stops.

Comment: I did verify, and backout count is the only property that can tell you if you use SYNCPOINT.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a horrible design.  If you are updating a database then why are you not using 2 phase commits (i.e. XA transactions)?

Just have your MQAdmin setup up the queue manager to use the resource manager of the particular database you are using then it is as simple as:

- Start transaction (2 phase commit)
- Get message (destructive get NOT browse) from the queue
- Update database
- Commit transaction

Hence, everything in the transaction, MQGET and database update, will either be committed together or backed out together.

If your application were to crash, then the resource manager will automatically back out everything in the transaction.

---

Lets say you don't want to use 2 phase commit or you are not updating a database (updating a file) then you can use single phase UOW (Unit of Work).

- Use MQGMO option of MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
- Get message (destructive get NOT browse) from the queue
- Update whatever you are updating
- Issue MQCMIT

Things to know about MQ:

- If an application issues an ***MQDISC or ends normally***, with current uncommitted operations, an ***implied MQCMIT is executed*** by IBM MQ, i.e. all operations done under SYNCPOINT are committed.
- If an application ***ends abnormally***, with current uncommitted operations, an ***implied MQBACK is executed*** by IBM MQ, i.e. all operations done under SYNCPOINT are rolled back.

Comment: Since there are many different "input channels" (MQ is just one way of getting data) and many ways to process the data, I'd rather not have a different solution when using a database as destination.
While your first suggestion could solve the problem, I potentially would need to have an implementation for each combination of input and output.
Your second suggestion has the same issue as mine: if the application dies just after your thrid step ("Update whatever you are updating") the message is backed out and will be reprocessed after restart.